# VSP2340 Environment variable issues suddenly when profiling an app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, profiling, environment-variables, memory-profiling

Can anybody explain why i'm suddenly getting this when trying to do any kind of performance profiling (the same way i always have) from within VS2012.

```
VSP2340: Environment variables were not properly set during profiling run and managed symbols may not resolve.  Please use vsperfclrenv before profiling.
```

I've googled and tried a few things, but i'm unable to find out how to get this working from within VS2012 again.

I found somebody with the same unanswered issue a couple of weeks back here: [VS2013: "VSP2340: Environment variables were not properly set" even when running from IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180205/vs2013-vsp2340-environment-variables-were-not-properly-set-even-when-running)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue on Visual Studio 2012. Follow the steps below:

- Start - All Programs - Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 - Visual Studio Tools
- Right click "Open VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt" and select run as administrator
- The command prompt opens. Run `vsperfclrenv /globalsampleon`
- Reboot machine

Comment: also works on Visual Studio 2015. The only drawback is that "edit and continue" doesn't work any longer. It can be reverted by executing `vsperfclrenv /globaloff`